# Creating Cron Jobs in magento?

Tags: magento-1.8, php-5.4, cron

I am new to `magento`, I have created the Module which is `Auto Replenish`. Here admin can schedule orders based on user conviviality like `Daily,Weekly,Monthly or Yearly`. For this I have written the code and showing the design on admin panel perfect. Here I have little bit of doubt to struck, **how to validate 
(ex:1 if I select Daily disable date,
    2 If I select Weekly Enable week days ...etc..) 
and how to create** `crontab event` **for this. Is this Idea is correct or wrong Any Idea ?**.

**my code is:**
**magento\app\code\local\Easylife\Autoreplenish\Block\Adminhtml\Autoreplenish\Edit\Tab\Form.php**

```
<?php
class Easylife_Autoreplenish_Block_Adminhtml_Autoreplenish_Edit_Tab_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{

    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
        $this->setForm($form);

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('autoreplenish_form',
            array('legend'=>'Auto Replenish Information'));

        $fieldset->addField('customer_name', 'text',
            array(
                'label' => 'Customer Name',
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => true,
                'name' => 'customer_name',
            ));
        $fieldset->addField('customer_email', 'text',
            array(
                'label' => 'Customer Email',
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => true,
                'name' => 'customer_email',
            ));
        $fieldset->addField('mobile_number', 'text',
            array(
                'label' => 'Phone Number',
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => true,
                'name' => 'mobile_number',
            ));
$fieldset->addField('sku', 'text',
            array(
                'label' => 'Item SKU',
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => true,
                'name' => 'sku',
            ));

        $fieldset->addField('select', 'select', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('autoreplenish')->__('Frequency'),
            'class' => 'required-entry',
            'required' => true,
            'name' => 'title',
            'onclick' => "",
            'onchange' => "",
            'values' => array('-1'=>'Please Select..','1' => 'Daily','2' => 'Weekly', '3' => 'Monthly', '4' => 'Yearly'),
            'disabled' => false,
            'readonly' => false,
            'after_element_html' => 'Select Frequency',
            'tabindex' => 1
        ));


        $fieldset->addField('date', 'date', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('autoreplenish')->__('Date'),
            'after_element_html' => 'Date',
            'image' => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
            'format' => Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_MEDIUM)
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('time', 'time', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('autoreplenish')->__('Time'),
            'class' => 'required-entry',
            'required' => true,
            'name' => 'time',
            'onclick' => "",
            'onchange' => "",
            'disabled' => false,
            'readonly' => false,
            'after_element_html' => 'Time',
            'tabindex' => 1
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('select2', 'select', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('autoreplenish')->__('Active'),
            'class' => 'required-entry',
            'required' => true,
            'name' => 'title',
            'onclick' => "",
            'onchange' => "",
            'values' => array('-1'=>'Please Select..','1' => 'Yes','2' => 'No'),
            'disabled' => false,
            'readonly' => false,
            'tabindex' => 1
        ));


        if ( Mage::registry('autoreplenish_data') )
        {
            $form->setValues(Mage::registry('autoreplenish_data')->getData());
        }
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

**magento\app\code\local\Easylife\Autoreplenish\etc\config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Autoreplenish>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Easylife_Autoreplenish>
    </modules>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <!--<autoreplenish>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Easylife_Autoreplenish</module>
                    <frontName>autoreplenish</frontName>
                </args>
            </autoreplenish>-->
            <customer>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <autoreplenish before="Mage_Customer">Easylife_Autoreplenish_Customer</autoreplenish>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </customer>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <autoreplenish>
                    <file>autoreplenish.xml</file>
                </autoreplenish>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>

    <admin>

        <routers>
            <autoreplenish>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Easylife_Autoreplenish</module>
                    <frontName>autoreplenish</frontName>
                </args>
            </autoreplenish>
        </routers>
    </admin>

    <global>
        <models>
            <autoreplenish>
                <class>Easylife_Autoreplenish_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>autoreplenish_resource</resourceModel>
            </autoreplenish>
            <autoreplenish_resource>
                <class>Easylife_Autoreplenish_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <autoreplenish>
                        <table>autoreplenish</table>
                    </autoreplenish>
                </entities>
            </autoreplenish_resource>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <autoreplenish_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Easylife_Autoreplenish</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </autoreplenish_setup>
            <autoreplenish_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </autoreplenish_read>
            <autoreplenish_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </autoreplenish_write>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <autoreplenish>
                <class>Easylife_Autoreplenish_Block</class>
            </autoreplenish>
            <autoreplenish_admin>
                <class>Easylife_Autoreplenish_Block_Adminhtml</class>
            </autoreplenish_admin>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <autoreplenish>
                <class>Easylife_Autoreplenish_Helper</class>
            </autoreplenish>
        </helpers>
    </global>

    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <autoreplenish translate="title" module="autoreplenish">
                <title>Auto Replenish</title>
                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                <children>
                    <development translate="title" module="autoreplenish">
                        <title>Auto Replenish Settings</title>
                        <action>autoreplenish/adminhtml_index</action>
                        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                    </development>
                </children>
            </autoreplenish>
        </menu>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <autoreplenish translate="title" module="autoreplenish">
                            <title>Auto Replenish</title>
                            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                            <children>
                                <development translate="title" module="autoreplenish">
                                    <title>Auto Replenish Settings</title>
                                    <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                                </development>
                            </children>
                        </autoreplenish>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <autoreplenish>
                    <file>autoreplenish.xml</file>
                </autoreplenish>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>

</config>
```

Waiting for Expert's Idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

These are two questions, therefore I recommend to open two questions.

## hide/show selects based on input

You can add a layout.xml file to your module in adminhtml, then add a JS file and implement the hiding and showing.

## Crontab

What is your exact problem? There are plenty of good tutorials out there.

- [Magento Wiki](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job)
- [Magento Configurable Cron](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento-configurable-cron/)
- [Creating cron script in Magento](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/creating-cron-script-in-magento/)